# Uses of the word "lyrics"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I would like to know how the word *lyrics* is used by a native English speaker.

The Concise Oxford English Dictionary says: *lyric* noun (also *lyrics*) the words of a song.

Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary says: the words of a song ― often used in plural.

So, I can guess that *lyric* could be used as a singular word, but I want to be sure that it is commonly used.

When we talk about what a singer says in a song we are talking about the *lyrics*.

By using the Internet, I can download all the *lyrics* of an artist. What happens if I want just one? I will download *one lyric*, *the lyrics of one song* or both ways are correct?

I read that the word *lyric* is related to poems but what happens in this case.

Likewise, in the context menu of some lyrics software, if I want to edit the lyrics of a song, which is the best option "edit the lyric" or "edit lyrics"?

Comment: Pretty sure most dictionaries should explain this.  Which one failed to do so, that we might disrecommend it in future?

Comment: This question can be improved by meeting the research requirement. It is at risk of being closed, and ultimately deleted.

Comment: I would like to know how it is used by a native speaker. The Concise Oxford English Dictionary says: lyric (also lyrics) the words of a song. Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary says: the words of a song ― often used in plural. So, I can guess that _lyric_ could be used as a singular word, but I want to be sure that it is commonly used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to attempt to answer this question specifically in the context of modern American colloquial usage of *lyric* and *lyrics*, specifically in the sense of words sung in a song, since that appears to be OP's focus. I'm basing this on personal experience on (i.e., countless hours of discussing music with friends).

I'd define the *common usage* of the word *lyric* (singular) as:

> a cohesive group of the words in a song, esp. a phrase, line, couplet or verse

Typically, a *lyric* is a standalone unit containing words of a song - a piece of the whole. Often the piece is distinct enough that it may standalone outside the context of the song and still make (some) sense.

*Lyrics* (plural) would refer to multiple such units. In general, a single song has multiple pieces: lines, verses, etc. As @AndrewLeach noted in his comment, one would refer to all of the words of a song as the *lyrics of a song*.

Here are some examples:

> Martin Scorsese's documentary *No Direction Home* takes its name from the Bob Dylan *lyric*: "How does it feel / To be on your own / With no direction home / Like a complete unknown / Like a rolling stone?"
>
> He loved the *lyrics* to "Like a Rolling Stone."
>
> He's a fan of Bob Dylan's *lyrics*.

Answer (score 3):

I would add that in most forms of everyday conversation all that is needed is never referring to poetry unless in educational settings.

"The, that lyric" for specifying one line or stanza of a song

"The, those, lyrics" for an entire song

Answer (score 1):

*Lyric* can be an adjective or a noun. See [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lyric?region=uk&q=lyric) for example, reproduced below. Where you found that "*lyric* is related to poetry" it would be used as an adjective, I expect.

> *adjective*
>
> 1 (of poetry) expressing the writer’s emotions, usually briefly and in stanzas or recognized forms: lyric poems of extraordinary beauty denoting a writer of lyric poetry: the lyric poets of Ancient Greece
>      2 (of a singing voice) using a light register: a lyric soprano with a light, clear timbre
>
> *noun*
>   (usually ***lyrics***)
>
> 1a lyric poem or verse: an edition of Horace’s *Lyrics*
>       [mass noun] lyric poetry as a literary genre: stylistic categories fundamental to literary aesthetics—epic, lyric, drama, comedy, tragedy
>      2 the words of a popular song: she has published both music and lyrics for a number of songs

A publishing house might refer to a particular *lyric* meaning the words of a single, particular, song, precisely to differentiate it from *lyrics* in general. But that's a particular usage which might not be evident from a dictionary entry (and isn't really apparent in ODO).

It's definitely an ordinary countable noun, so it's *a lyric* (meaning a single song) or *the lyrics of a song*; and you can't **edit lyric* because that needs an article before *lyric*.

Comment: So, continuing with my example, I will download one lyric. And then, I can edit _the_ lyric. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, ***but*** it's an **unusual and specialised usage** to use *lyric* to mean a single song rather than the phrase *lyrics of a song*. In general, use *lyrics* and rely on context to determine whether it means the words of a particular song, or (say) all the words in an opera or musical.

Answer (score -1):

- Lyrical- pertaining to theatre, drama, poetry, and artful use of speech.
- Lyrics- Words to a song.
- Lyre- ancient stringed instrument often accompanied by song.
- Lyric- Thus I don't think this is a word.

Comment: PLEASE punctuate your answers and break them into proper sentences and paragraphs.

Comment: Also please do not simply write answers based on how you think things are without even bothering to check a dictionary. ‘Lyric’ is most certainly a word, as any dictionary worth its salt (and even some not quite worth their salt) will tell you. While this answer does address the etymology of ‘lyric’ and is therefore not without merit, its answer to the actual question at hand is incorrect.

Comment: The question was whether it is common to use the word 'lyric' in the singular sense to refer to songs/ The answer is no, which if I answered it this way, my answer would be too plain and add no further interest. I helped out by adding where lyrics is commonly used: in the theatre, and that it comes from the word lyre. I also spoke the truth- the word 'lyric' is not commonly used in the english language, which is what the original question was, I must remind you.

Comment: My comment box will not allow me to create paragraphs on any and all of my comments that I have posted in the past 2 days since I have registered on this site. I have tried multiple times to create paragraphs and when I press the save button, all of my sentences get pressed together automatically, so it is not my fault, but this website's.

Comment: @Julie Agreed the answer box editing tools are not the most intuitive in the world, but if you take the time to sit, explore the help pages, read, you will find ways round the formatting limitations. If I managed, anyone can! See this link for further help. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: A "thank you" would have been nice...